# Как правильно наложить текстуру веревки на тетиву?

Tags: blender, текстура

добавил текстуру веревки на тетиву, а она растянута.
Как исправить, чтобы было чётко видно веревку?

**Растянутая текстура тетивы**

[image: Растянутая текстура тетивы]

**Текстура**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сделать текстурную развертку модели тетевы и корректно спроецировать изображение на получившуюся развертку.

Если кратко:
1) зайти в Edit Mode [Tab]

2) поскольку форма тетивы - по сути, аналог цилиндра, нужно развернуть ее подобно цилиндру.
Выделить вертикальное ребро и выполнить команду Select -> Edge loops

3) отметить их швами с помощью операции **Mark Seam**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4) выделить сегменты для развертки (все) [A], развернуть геометрию и выполнить команду [U] -> Unwrap

5) корректировка получившейся развертки в окне UV/Image Editor
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это очень грубый пример. Лучше, конечно, чтобы текстурная развертка не выходила за пределы рабочей области и "красить" развертку текстурами лучше в 2д-редакторе.

Comment: Извиняюсь, нужно одно ребро выбрать?

Comment: Я дополнил ответ.